# Access DOM of external .HTML from NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, io, document.write

New to NodeJS and JavaScript in general; how do I do basic file I/O?

#### read_and_edit_me.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="//foo">bar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### rw_dom.js

```js
// Here is how I would do it if this was in <head></head>
document.open();
document.write('<a href="/bar">Out with the old -');
document.write('<a href="/new_bar">in</a> with the new!</a>');

var all_href = [], l = document.links;
document.close();

for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    all_href.push(l[i].href);
}

// `all_href` should contain: ["http://{host}/bar", "http://{host}/new_bar"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but you have some quote mistakes on the 2nd line of rw_dom.js.
It should be
`"<a href='//bar'>Out with the old - in with the new!</a>"`

Comment: Yeah, realised that just before I got your new comment alert. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to manipulate DOM serverside before sending it to the client?
If so, take a look at this (using "jsdom"):
http://marksoper.me/Server-side-DOM-manipulation-in-Nodejs-with-JSDOM-JQuery-and-Mustache-Templates-April-25-2011.html

Answer (score 0):

@MattiasHognas didn't accept my edit, so going off his link this is what I am thinking was meant:

```
require.paths.unshift('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');
var fs    = require('fs'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom');

var read_and_edit_me = fs.readFileSync('read_and_edit_me.html','utf-8');
var document         = jsdom.jsdom(read_and_edit_me);
```

Then `document` should be able to used as in my question's snippet?

Comment: Based on my assumption that you want to modify the DOM of content you're sending back to the client, then yes, document in that case is the root DOM node of the content just as if it where client side.